# Facebook login for web and device generate different uid for same user

Tags: facebook

We are trying to update Facebook login for a device and found out different uid generated while login via PC browser and device login method. The uid generated by browser can get user feeds, but it return empty for uid generated by device login. Does anyone know why there is different uid for same user?

Answer (score 0):

It's by design so that unrelated apps can't correlate their users.

Straight [from the upgrade docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids), emphasis mine;

> 1. App-scoped User IDs
>
> Facebook will begin to issue app-scoped user IDs when people first log into an instance of your app coded against v2.0 of the API. **With app-scoped IDs, the ID for the same user will be different between apps**.
>
> No matter what version they originally used to sign up for your app, the ID will remain the same for people who have already logged into your app. This change is backwards-compatible for anyone who has logged into your app at any point in the past.
>
> If you're not mapping IDs across apps, then no code changes should be required. **If you need to map the same user IDs across multiple apps or run cross-app promotions, we've added a new API called the Business Mapping API. This lets you map a logged-in user's IDs across apps as long as those apps are all owned by the same business.**

Comment: Hi, we try to get uid from "Business Mapping API" but this uid is still same as uid obtained from device login method. And, use this uid to get user's feed and it still return empty data. Any further advice? Thanks.